# Django - How to display user's profile picture with a message after its sent?

Tags: javascript, python, django, web, chat

I have a live chat application and I'm trying to display a profile picture with the message after its sent with Javascript. Here is my code...

**Models.py** - here is my Message and Profile model

```
class Message(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date_added', )

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

**Consumers.py**

```
class ChatRoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
async def connect(self):
    self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
    self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
    print(self.room_group_name)

    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    await self.accept()

async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

async def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']
    username = text_data_json['username']
    room = text_data_json['room']

    await self.save_message(username, room, message)

    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chatroom_message',
            'message': message,
            'username': username,
        }
    )

async def chatroom_message(self, event):
    message = event['message']
    username = event['username']

    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'message': message,
        'username': username,
    }))

@sync_to_async
def save_message(self, username, room, message):
    user = User.objects.get(username = username)
    Message.objects.create(author = user, room = room, content = message)

pass
```

And here is the **Javascript** code for the live chat...

```
{{ request.user.username|json_script:"user_username" }}
{{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}
<script>
    const user_username = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_username').textContent);
    document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = function (e) {
        const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#input');
        const message = messageInputDom.value;
        if(message.trim() == ''){
        }
        else {
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message,
            'username': user_username,
            'room': roomName,
        }));
        messageInputDom.value = '';
        }
    };
    const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);

    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' +
        window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' +
        roomName +
        '/'
    );

    chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(data)
        if (data.message) {
                document.querySelector('#chat-text').innerHTML += ('<img id="imageid" src="{{ message.author.profile.image.url }}">' + data.username + '<br>' + data.message + '<br>');
            }
        else {

        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is with this `<img id="imageid" src="{{ message.author.profile.image.url }}">` in the **Javascript** code. So my question is, how can I display the user's profile picture with the message after its sent without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use AJAX here, you are communicating with the server via WebSockets, you can get the data you need through it.

Looks like you are using django-channels. Check django-channels [documentation about authentication](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/authentication.html#authentication). If you enable it, you will be able to access the current user through `self.scope['user']`.

So, you will able to do something like this:

```
async def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']
    username = self.scope['user'].username
    profile_pic = self.scope['user'].profile.image.url  # None handling required
    room = text_data_json['room']

    await self.save_message(username, room, message)

    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chatroom_message',
            'message': message,
            'username': username,
            'profile_pic': profile_pic
        }
    )

async def chatroom_message(self, event):
    message = event['message']
    username = event['username']
    profile_pic = event['profile_pic']

    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'message': message,
        'username': username,
        'profile_pic': profile_pic
    }))

 # on the frontend
 chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(data)
        if (data.message) {
                document.querySelector('#chat-text').innerHTML += (`<img id="imageid" src="${data.profile_pic}">` + data.username + '<br>' + data.message + '<br>');
            }
        else {
            
        }
```

Note that you can't make database calls from async context because database connector works in a synchronous manner.
When you are getting a profile pic `self.scope['user'].profile.image.url` you are actually making a DB call to get user's profile.

What you need to do in such cases is make a db call using either `database_sync_to_async` or `sync_to_async` decorators.

For example:

```
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

@database_sync_to_async
def get_user_profile(self):
    return self.scope['user'].profile
 
# and in receive method you call it
async def receive(self, text_data):
    profile = await self.get_user_profile()
    profile_pic = profile.image.url
    ....
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I have enabled the AuthMiddleware, but I get the following error:  You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

Comment: I updated the answer. To make DB calls from async context you need to extract them into separate functions wrapped in `@database_sync_to_async` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to refresh only a part of the webpage, with a different HTML document, containing the Django HTML to display the profile picture.

Comment: You can use Ajax in javascript to create an image element and then call the django server to display the image in it. You can do this for any new message. Any small part of the HTML document. Even just one line if you need to.